# What is the ratio of gender in battle spots of Pokemon ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I have a Haxorus who has the ability, Rivalry(Raises Attack if the foe is of the same gender), so I wonder which gender is more suitable in ORAS batttle spots and competitive battles.

After going though battle in free, I have seen a lot of male Pokemons. However for breeding purposes, I think that females are more useful, so maybe more females will appear in the future. I need an answer for overall gender ratios in battle spots and suggestion for future preparation.

Thank you, my Pokemon Comrades.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that not a single person cares about gender for battles, and as such it's completely random, keeping in mind that Pokémon can have gender ratios that are not 1:1.

I don't see why you would willingly use Rivalry when Haxorus can have Mold Breaker.

Comment: That's not totally true, I've heard several people that want to have only males in their team. It's a bit sexist, but whatever. I prefer females because I like to pass down their Pokeball.

Comment: The rare person that has Attract on their Pokémon would care about gender, although that isn't very common nowadays.

Comment: @JustinTime But that depends on the opponent's Pokémon too, and you can't predict that.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer True, which is probably why it's so rare.  I think the place it caught on the most was in old online battle programs like Shoddy Battle, which defaulted to everything being male (if I remember correctly); I've seen it a few times outside there, but not very often.

Answer (score 0):

Even if females are more useful for breeding, that changes nothing when it comes to a pokemon that is bred correctly, because its all about IV's, abilities and moveset, and all of those are gender-independent. It is completely down to gender ratios being different, and the trend there is you're more likely to encounter a male pokemon, because there are more all-male pokemon than all-female and because if the gender ratio is skewed, its usually mostly male and rarely female (for instance, starters are 7/8ths male and 1/8th female).